# Import error: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of python

Tags: python, pygame, importerror

import sys
sys.path.insert(1,"C:/Users/ravir_000/Desktop/python_CS105/python_CS105/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
import math
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

How do you get rid of the error? Import error: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of python. I was working on this a few hours ago and it was working fine. When I got into class it started giving me this error. I have tried to install/reinstall pyscripter and pygame but it still does not work. I am sure that my path to pygame is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a pygame distribution that is for python 2.7 with a different version of python.

You should download and use the appropriate version.

If installed correctly, there will be no need for `sys.path.insert`.